# Using objects inside objects when it is part of another variable

Tags: javascript

I want to output the name of an object property ("sword"). I figure I should be able to do this by using

```
player.weapon.name
```

I have no trouble doing this when everything is nested inside one object, but when trying to take a property (name) from another variable (sword) the application breaks when clicking the "Equip" button. After testing I am sure that this is due to

```
player.weapon.name
```

not behaving properly.

This popup provided by vscode (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1sBE.png) suggests that player.weapon.name should work. I've also tried bracket notation to no avail. What is the proper syntax for referencing this property?

```
// DOM Variables
var equipButton = document.getElementById('equip-button');

// UI Variables
var equipQuery = false;

// Player Variables
var player = {
  name: "Player",
  health: 100,
  armor: 0,
  strength: 1,
  accuracy: 80,
  knowledge: 0,
  weapon: sword,
};

equipButton.style.display = 'none';

showStatus();

// Button Handlers

equipButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  equipQuery = true;
  showStatus();
});

// Write Screen

function showStatus() {
  if (equipQuery == true) { // Clicked Equip Button
    textArea.innerText = "You are wielding " + player.weapon.name;

    equipQuery = false; // Let's turn off the equip query

    equipButton.style.display = 'none'; // Sets the buttons such that the player can go back

    return;
  }

  textArea.innerText = "Your name is " +    player.name; // Default Text

}

// Item Objects

var sword = {
  name: "sword",
  bigname: "Sword",
  strength: 0,
  accuracy: 0,
  type: null,
};
```

Comment: You should define `sword` before you use it.

Comment: Solved. Had to move the sword variable and its properties up above the player variable in order for it to be declared properly. That was embarrassing. Remember to define your variables before you reference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `sword` before you actually assign a value to it, therefore it is `undefined` (`console.log(player)` to verify that) and thus you can't access it's `name`.

That was just possible because you used `var` which allows for such mistakes, use `let` or `const` (for values that do not change) instead, then it'll point out those errors.

```
  let player = { weapon: sword }; // error: variable used before declaration

  const sword = {};
```

Comment: Solved, thank you. I'll use `let` from now on, and make sure to declare variables before they are used.